# Django Rest Serializer: How to use id when create or update, and get hyperlink when read,?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

`models.py`

```py
class User(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=300)

class Booking(models.Model):
    time = models.DateTimeField()
    user_id = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='booking', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

`serializers.py`

```py
class UserSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = '__all__'

class BookingSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Booking
        fields = '__all__'
```

With the above code, I would get an error `user_id ":["Incorrect type. Expected URL string, received int."]` during creating booking process. I believe this because `HyperlinkedModelSerializer` expect a URL for the foreign key field. However, passing an ID during creating or updating is way more convenient. How can I edit this so that it can use id when create or update and return hyperlink only when read?

Comment: can you tell why you are using HyperLinkedModelSerializers?

Comment: It would be very convenient to read the data generally. If the method that I am trying to implement is impossible, I might revert back to ModelSerializer.

Comment: no its possible but we have simple model serializer so you can use it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not bound to use one serializer per viewset. By overriding [`get_serializer_class`](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/generic-views/#get_serializer_classself) method, we are able to use different serializers based on the view action. In this case a `ModelSerializer` when creating objects:

serializers.py

```py
class UserSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    ...

class BookingSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Booking
        fields = ['url', 'user_id', 'time']

class BookingUserIDSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Booking
        fields = ['user_id', 'time']
```

views.py

```py
class UserViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = get_user_model().objects.all()
    serializer_class = UserSerializer

class BookingViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Booking.objects.all()
    serializer_class = BookingSerializer

    def get_serializer_class(self):
        if self.action == 'create':
            return BookingUserIDSerializer

        return self.serializer_class
```

The same process can be used for updating.

Comment: Thank you! It looks like dynamically use serializer class based on the action is the way to go.